# json_decode() doesn't work in Payment Gateway Plugin for WHMCS Callback File

Tags: php, json, payment-gateway, whmcs

I have an interesting challenge here working with whmcs.

I am writing a Plugin to integrate a payment gateway into a whmcs installation.

I have completed the first part of the plugin which is to add the payment button which triggers the payment gateway modal and facilitates the payment.

After payment succeeds or fails, the payment gateway redirects back to whmcs callback url with a get parameter that looks like this.

https://www.domainname.com/whmcs/modules/gateways/callback/gateway.php?resp=urlencoded-json-string

exact sample response from payment gateway 
https://www.domainname.com/whmcs/modules/gateways/callback/gateway.php?resp=%7B%22name%22%3A%22vbvcomplete%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%22successful%22%2C%22txRef%22%3A%22316_1514108957%22%2C%22amount%22%3A%222%22%7D%7D%2C%22respcode%22%3A%2200%22%2C%22tx%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A61282%2C%22txRef%22%3A%22316_1514108957%22%2C%22orderRef%22%3A%22URF_1514109007270_1408935%22%2C%22flwRef%22%3A%22FLW-MOCK-6ef5fba0e6d6eaf49b367f3728bf7901%22%2C%22redirectUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fwhmcs%2Fmodules%2Fgateways%2Fcallback%2Fwhmcs.php%3Finvoiceid%3D316%22%2C%22device_fingerprint%22%3A%22bb6c9abc3306a4902ed9fcfda80ff51d%22%2C%22settlement_token%22%3Anull%2C%22cycle%22%3A%22one-time%22%2C%22amount%22%3A2%2C%22charged_amount%22%3A2%2C%22appfee%22%3A0.1288961038961039%2C%22merchantfee%22%3A0%2C%22merchantbearsfee%22%3A1%2C%22chargeResponseCode%22%3A%2200%22%2C%22raveRef%22%3A%22RV31514109005971CBADF3EFDF%22%2C%22chargeResponseMessage%22%3A%22Success-Pending-otp-validation%22%2C%22authModelUsed%22%3A%22VBVSECURECODE%22%2C%22currency%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22IP%22%3A%22129.56.12.21%22%2C%22narration%22%3A%22FLW-PBF+CARD+Transaction+%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22successful%22%2C%22vbvrespmessage%22%3A%22Approved.+Successful%22%2C%22authurl%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fflw-pms-dev.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com%2Fmockvbvpage%3Fref%3DFLW-MOCK-6ef5fba0e6d6eaf49b367f3728bf7901%26code%3D00%26message%3DApproved.+Successful%26receiptno%3DRN1514109007311%22%2C%22vbvrespcode%22%3A%2200%22%2C%22acctvalrespmsg%22%3Anull%2C%22acctvalrespcode%22%3A%22RN1514109007311%22%2C%22paymentType%22%3A%22card%22%2C%22paymentPlan%22%3Anull%2C%22paymentPage%22%3Anull%2C%22paymentId%22%3A%222%22%2C%22fraud_status%22%3A%22ok%22%2C%22charge_type%22%3A%22normal%22%2C%22is_live%22%3A0%2C%22createdAt%22%3A%222017-12-24T09%3A50%3A07.000Z%22%2C%22updatedAt%22%3A%222017-12-24T09%3A50%3A28.000Z%22%2C%22deletedAt%22%3Anull%2C%22customerId%22%3A10575%2C%22AccountId%22%3A907%2C%22customer%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A10575%2C%22phone%22%3Anull%2C%22fullName%22%3A%22Anonymous+customer%22%2C%22customertoken%22%3Anull%2C%22email%22%3A%22customeremail%40gmail.com%22%2C%22createdAt%22%3A%222017-12-24T09%3A50%3A06.000Z%22%2C%22updatedAt%22%3A%222017-12-24T09%3A50%3A06.000Z%22%2C%22deletedAt%22%3Anull%2C%22AccountId%22%3A907%7D%2C%22chargeToken%22%3A%7B%22user_token%22%3A%2207924%22%2C%22embed_token%22%3A%22flw-t0-9a321f32b799b489796ffc44a63a5762-m03k%22%7D%7D%2C%22respmsg%22%3A%22Approved.+Successful%22%7D

The next easy thing to do would be to collect the $_GET['resp'] parameter and decode it like so

```
<?php
// Require libraries needed for gateway module functions.
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../init.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../includes/gatewayfunctions.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../includes/invoicefunctions.php';


 $response = $_GET['resp'];

 $response = json_decode($response);
 // and access the values like
 $response->tx->amount //10.00
```

However, The Json_decode fails and returns null like if the json was improperly formatted.

After further investigation.

I realised, if test this exact url string on a non whmcs installation, the json_decode works fine and i can access the data as object or associative array.

When i remove the line below from the gateway callback file. It works fine. It seems to be the whmcs application that is messing with the json function.

```
    // Require libraries needed for gateway module functions.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../init.php';
```

But the payment gateway callback cannot work with out the necessary headers in place, especially the init.php file.

How can i handle this scenario and get past this.

Thanks.

Comment: The CMS is more likely interfering with the $_GET variable than with core functions. Try reading the $_GET before the init and see if that helps.

Comment: looks to be url encoded as well

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Thanks a lot for the tip. I collected the $_GET value before the require_once statements. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out thanks to the suggestion by @GerardVanHelden that WHMCS might be messing up the $_GET value.

So i Just Collected the $_GET value before the require_once statements.
and json_decode worked as normal.

Cheers.